# Wireless connection drops every couple minutes

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-adapter

A HP notebook with Windows 10 we have drops wireless connection every couple minutes. I've installed latest drivers (from June 17) and that did not help. I've search around the system and got to `WLAN-AutoConfig` events, where every couple minutes (correlated with the disconnecting) three events appeared:

`Wireless security stopped. Event ID 11004 Security Hint: The operation succeeds.`

(couple seconds when wifi does not work)

`Wireless security started. Event ID 11010`

`Wireless security succeeded. Event ID 11005`

(wifi works again)

I think that the two other events (`11010` and `11005`) are called because we have checked 'automatically connect to the wireless network', without that I think it only drops the connection with `11004` and stops.

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT** This also happens for the same network when logged under Safe Mode.

**EDIT 2** Tested another network, the issue does not happen! Encryption of the second network is WPA2-Personal, and encryption type is AES (not sure about the original network now, keeping this for reference). Also, the working network uses 802.11g, the dropping either 802.11n or 802.11ac , not sure now.

**EDIT 3** I've found multiple references to this problem online and it seems it's an Intel cards vs Windows 10 issue. Some support online recommended setting "Roaming Aggressiveness" to "1. Lowest." and HT mode to HT (from VHT). While this didn't stop the three events from occurring, it made them occur "faster" after each other, which is good - effectively reducing the downtime to around one second max.

<s>After reading the threads online I'm think I'll just buy another wireless card.</s>

**EDIT 4** More experiments! After setting the wireless security on router from WPA2-Personal + AES to WPA-Personal + AES, everything seems to be working correctly. I also tried WPA or WPA2-Personal mode on the router, but that had the same issues as WPA2 (I think because the driver *thinks* it knows how to properly WPA2 but actually it does not so well). As the computer is mainly on our home network, setting the security to WPA-Personal + AES is a ok solution for us.

Comment: I had the same problem, security keeps restarting by itself and autoconfig thing. I'm a computer engineering student but I'm not really a fan of networks. Been struggling with this problem for 2 years until I found this thread. I don't know how to thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If problem only happens on specific wifi network, such as home wifi network, try to check/update your network device(such as router) firmware/driver and check the result.

If latest NIC driver version is not helpful, you may try previous driver version and check the result. make sure that the driver is applied to applied to your NIC hardware model and supports Windows 10.

Re-start system in Safe Mode with Network enabled, and check the result. if problem does not happen again, try to narrow down the problem during 3rd party process on your system.

Comment: It happens in the Safe Mode as well. If it did happen only on the one wifi, do you think it's possible that the issue is with some security setting between the wifi and the computer?